# vim substitution : # for a single $ and nothing to do if $$

Tags: regex, vim, replace, pattern-matching

I would like to do the following substitution : replace `$` of words located between 2 `$` by the symbol # and do nothing if these words are between 2 `$$`.

For example, in this text :

```
Currently, we are able to make cross correlations (understand "combine" to have better constraints on cosmological parameters) between weak lensing (WL) and photometric Galaxy clustering (GCph). When I say combine, as in the case where I have 2 sets of different measures ($\tau_1, \sigma_1$) and ($\tau_2, \sigma_2$), well, if I consider the Gaussian errors, it is shown quite easily (by Maximum Likelihood Estimation) that the estimator $\sigma_{\hat {\tau}}$ the most representative matches the relation:
    
    
$$\dfrac{1}{\sigma_{\hat{\tau}}^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}$$
```

The substitution would give :

```
Currently, we are able to make cross correlations (understand "combine" to have better constraints on cosmological parameters) between weak lensing (WL) and photometric Galaxy clustering (GCph). When I say combine, as in the case where I have 2 sets of different measures (#\tau_1, \sigma_1#) and (#\tau_2, \sigma_2#), well, if I consider the Gaussian errors, it is shown quite easily (by Maximum Likelihood Estimation) that the estimator #\sigma_{\hat {\tau}}# the most representative matches the relation:


$$\dfrac{1}{\sigma_{\hat{\tau}}^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}$$
```

I tried to perform this with the following command under vim :

```
%s/\$[^\$]\(.*\)\$[^\$]/#\1#/g
```

or

```
%s/\$[^\$]\(.\{-}\)\$[^\$]/#\1#/g
```

But this doesn't work. I can't see my error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex replacement in `vim` using negative lookahead and negative lookbehind:

**Search:**

```
:%s/\v\$@<!\$([^$]+)\$\$@!/#\1#/g
```

**Replacement:**

```
#\1#
```

**Explanation:**

- `%s/`: Global substitution
- `\v`: Start very magic mode instead of BRE
- `\$@<!`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have `$` at previous position
- `\$`: Match a literal `$`
- `([^$]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `$` and capture it in group #1
- `\$`: Match a literal `$`
- `\$@!`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `$` ahead
- `#\1#`: Replace with back-reference of group #1 surrounded with `#`

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you use `\(.*\)` or `\(.\{-}\)` to capture the group #1. I have difficulties to understand the `\$@<!` : `<` refers to previous position whereas `\$@!` refers to next position ?

Comment: `.*` or `.+` are greedy regex patterns not as efficient as `[^@]+`. Also use of lookahead and lookbehind is required here to avoid matching line with `$$ ... $$`. Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/nrOqBB/1

Comment: A very good tutorial on regex lookahead / lookbehind: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ! I am not familiar with `([^$]+)` to capture into  group `#1`, I usually use `\(.\{-}\)` or `\(.*\)` , I have to study this part deeper. Regards